# Make function by pspgsql pgadmin( In case ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression)

Tags: plpgsql, pgadmin

First pgr_dijkstra is
[image]

my code is

```
select di.seq, di.node , di.edge , di.cost, a.geom

from pgr_dijkstra(

    'select id, target, source, cost from pedroad', 

    (select get_source2('location1')),array(select get_target2('points')),false) 
as di, 

    pedroad a

    where di.node = a.source;
```

cf
`select get_source2('location1')` is[image]

`select get_target2('points')` is[image]

If I ran this code

result is
[image]

Now I have a question. 
I want to make function, so I try to like this.
my code

```
    create or replace function get_route2(snode integer, tnode integer)
returns setof geometry as
$$
declare 
    snode1 integer;
    tnode2 integer;
begin
    snode1 := snode;
    tnode2 := tnode;

    return query
        select di.seq, di.node, di.edge, di.cost, a.geom
    from pgr_dijkstra(
    'select id, target, source, cost from pedroad', 
    snode1, tnode2,false) as di,pedroad a
    where di.node = a.source;
end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then I ran this function like this

select get_route2((select get_source2('location1')),(select get_target2('points')))

ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Sadly,, I know there are many errors in my code...
However, I don't know what to do... Please help us !

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is very hard to read. Please consider to read and apply the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Please post code and data as *text*, not as image. and always disclose your version of Postgres.